Replacing USB-C socket on a keyboard
I decided to fix some of my stuff that has broken USB-C ports. (why are they so fragile!) I've removed the old sockets and cleaned the pads, but when the old sockets were damaged (by simply inserting the cable!) some pads were lifted. I'm pretty sure that a keyboard only uses four of the conductors in a USB cable - ground, Power and Data + and -
In this first photo, you can see that one pad is lifted.

In this case, I don't think the lifted pad is an issue. There doesn't seem to be a trace leading from it. The outer two pads are a little loose, but they both appear to be grounds. I'll check, but I'm 99% certain, so I can easily sort that out. So....is it safe to assume the pin that connects to that missing pad does nothing?
On this one, though, there are a couple of missing pads.

I haven't removed the old solder or cleaned the flux residue off yet, but you can see it has the same missing pad as the previous pic, so if that does nothing (these are both keyboards, by the way) then it's no problem. But it's also missing that second pin from the left. Is that used? Or do I have to see if there's enough of it left to get a continuity meter on it and go poking around to see where it goes?

Those pins are for the superspeed communication lines.  These are unlikely to be used by your keyboards.
The USB-2 type data lines that your keyboards probably use are in the center.
You are correct that the larger outer pads are ground.
LINK to USB C pinout guide and features


I wasn't sure how the pinout diagrams correspond to the pins at the back. So, I'm assuming I can just put new sockets in and they should both work. I'm also a little confused by why 12 and 16 pin sockets seem to be the same thing. Are they counting the little chassis tabs you use to mount them or something silly like that?

The pinouts usually match 1:1 because they don't cross over each other coming out of the connector.  I believe the 16 pin ones just have extra ground tabs that may add some mechanical stability.  Those look repairable...install a new connector and you should be good to go.

The connector does not have enough pins for SuperSpeed USB. So it can't be it. And the amount of pins on connector may not correlate with the amount of pads - it is perfectly normal to see wide GND and VBUS pads for two ground and two VBUS pins per pad.

First misconception : "I'm pretty sure that a keyboard only uses four of the conductors in a USB cable - ground, Power and Data + and - " is false. It is true on a Type-A port as it contains no other signals, but not with Type-C, as there are control pins that negotiate if there is anything connected and what role device it is to even determine if power should be turned on or not.
It does look like one unused pin is missing from first photo. There are different USB-C connectors with different pinouts available, and some pins can be unused, like the SBU and USB3 pins.
The second photo looks like has same connector and more pins torn off. Usually the two wide pads are for VBUS and GND, and as per the specs they all should be connected.

I can bridge the VBus pin to the one on the opposite side though, right? It's getting plugged into a normal USB 2.0 or 3.0 port on the PC, and there's only one power rail there, right? So they're all gonna be the same thing as far as I can see. Not sure though. Big old valve amps are more my thing.

@HaverfordWest But that depens on your PCB, not the connetor. Sure on the connector all four VBUS and all four GND pins should be same as that is the job of the plug to also tie these together and pass on to all four plug pins to four receptacle pins. Assuming you use a standard-compliant cable yes. A cheap online bought cable - no guarantees. Also the keyboard PCB would be expected to tie all four VBUS and four GNDs together, but you don't know if they do that until you try or measure it. It is possible the design is non-compliant and left/right pins are used for different purposes.
